# Pass Data on MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am using [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) in my app. When I want to pass data from MMExampleLeftSideDrawerViewController to MMExampleCenterTableViewController , I can't do that .

you can see MMExampleLeftSideDrawerViewController and MMExampleCenterTableViewController class inside of source code .
source code:  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7v83asitsejorl/MMDrawerController-pasdata.zip)

I added this codes :

**MMExampleCenterTableViewController.h**

```
-(void)doSomethingUseful:(NSString *)data;
```

**MMExampleCenterTableViewController.m**

```
-(void)doSomethingUseful:(NSString *)data
{
    NSLog(@"dosometing useful %@",data);
}
```

**MMExampleLeftSideDrawerViewController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MMExampleCenterTableViewController * mycenterController=(MMExampleCenterTableViewController *)self.mm_drawerController.centerViewController;

    [mycenterController doSomethingUseful:@"mydata"];

    //...........
}
```

When ı click tableview on  MMExampleLeftSideDrawerViewController , I have issue that you can see on source.

**issue log is :** 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MMNavigationController doSomethingUseful:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

So it's not same object's class.( `MMExampleCenterTableViewController * mycenterController=(MMExampleCenterTableViewController *)self.mm_drawerController.centerViewController;`  ).

How can I send data to MMExampleCenterTableViewController ?

Comment: @Alok please read my question exactly . I said I have issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like self.mm_drawerController.centerViewController is a navigation controller. The one you want is probably its topViewController, so try this:

```
 MMExampleCenterTableViewController * mycenterController= [(MMNavigationController *)self.mm_drawerController.centerViewController topViewController];
```

Comment: Thank you @rdelmar .it's working very well. But How you understand topviewController ? which case can we understand that ?

Comment: @ErhanDemirci, I'm not sure I understand your question. topViewController is a property of UINavigationController, and returns the controller at the top of the stack. If there's only one controller on the stack, it will be the root view controller of the navigation controller.